# Is $\mathbb{P}[A \leq x] = \mathbb{P}[G(A) \leq G(x)]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have come across this doubt when browsing through one of the chapters on function of random variables in a probability text book. I suppose if $G$ is a monotonic function, the equality holds?

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is not one-to-one there are counterexamples, with $G$ constant for example.

Comment: I see! I forgot that condition! Thanks for bringing it up. Now it all makes sense

Comment: Provided that G is strictly increasing,yes.